# how to pass muitiple $query variables in csv_from_result() method codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following query :

```
$query1 = $this->db->query(" SELECT * FROM `student_registration` "); 

$query2 = $this->db->query(" SELECT * FROM `club_registration` ");
```

Here I want to pass both query data in csv_from_result() of codeigniter and i am using like that :

```
$this->load->dbutil();
$delimiter = ",";
$newline = "\r\n";
$backup=$this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query, $delimiter, $newline);
$db_name = 'Students'.'_'. date('Y-m-d') .'.csv';
$this->load->helper('download');
force_download($db_name, $backup);
```

but in above `csv_from_result()` method how to pass `$query1` and `$query2` variable ?

Comment: Sorav Garg what solution did you find for this issues ?

Comment: Still not found.

Answer (score 0):

here is the library code of the utility function you are using.
You cannot pass multiple queries to this function.
$query parameter is the query result object here.

```
function csv_from_result($query, $delim = ",", $newline = "\n", $enclosure = '"')
{
    if ( ! is_object($query) OR ! method_exists($query, 'list_fields'))
    {
        show_error('You must submit a valid result object');
    }

    $out = '';

    // First generate the headings from the table column names
    foreach ($query->list_fields() as $name)
    {
        $out .= $enclosure.str_replace($enclosure, $enclosure.$enclosure, $name).$enclosure.$delim;
    }

    $out = rtrim($out);
    $out .= $newline;

    // Next blast through the result array and build out the rows
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
        foreach ($row as $item)
        {
            $out .= $enclosure.str_replace($enclosure, $enclosure.$enclosure, $item).$enclosure.$delim;
        }
        $out = rtrim($out);
        $out .= $newline;
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Correct usage of this function will be -

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM mytable");
echo $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query);
```

refer - https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/utilities.html

Comment: Thank You  For Answer, But  i have to fetch data from two tables then what is the solution for that...